# Does Java 8 Method references - can used only in consumer Functional Interfaces

Tags: java, java-8

I have been using Java 8 method references for quite some time, but i have this question in my mind.

i know that method references is a short hand notation for a lambda expression,which calls a single method (the method may be a static one or a constructor or method belonging to a instance object).

does this mean, method references can used only as a substitute for lambda of consumer functional interfaces?

For example

```
Consumer<String> c = s -> System.out.println(s);
```

can be rewritten as

```
 Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
```

And

```
Consumer<T> c=(args) -> Class.staticMethod(args)
```

can be re written as

```
Class::staticMethod
```

Comment: *does this mean, method references can used only as a substitute for lambda of consumer functional interfaces?* Not at all. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comeback. And welcome to upvote rights, which gives you even more ways of showing your appreciation ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean, method references can used only as a substitute for lambda of consumer functional interfaces?

No. Method references can be used in place of any lambda expression, as long as the signatures match. For example:

```
Function<Object, String> toString = Object::toString;
Function<Object, String> valueOf = String::valueOf;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it can for sure be written like that, this is close to the same thing under the hood. With a method reference, you are saving internally one more method call, usually it's a tiny method that can be easily inlined by JIT.

One more thing IMO, is that it is more readable in case of a method reference.

And of course your last point, is well, wrong. You can write for example:

```
Function<String, Integer> f = String::length
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes (regarding the "is it a shortcut"). You can only use a method reference where you would instead pass a lambda (or to be precise: the actual type of that lambda). The idea is that you pass "a piece of code" for later execution. A lambda is the generic form, allowing you to run *any* code you write down.

But especially when it is just about calling a specific method, why forcing the user of putting down a lambda?!

In other words: method references are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). They do not enrich Java with any *additional* functionality. They simple allow you to express a very common situation without the need to write down a complete lambda. To be precise: method references are just that: a shortcut for lambdas.

Comment: when u say *just* syntactic sugar, you usually say *for what* it is just that. But this is a bit incorrect too, as method references and lambdas are a bit more, for example anonymous inner classes capture `this`, even if not used, the other ones dont. Also the entire `this` meaning changes for a lambda. And of course an anonymous inner class always results in a new instance, lambdas, might not. There are other internal differences too

Comment: My original question was that,can method references only be used as substitution for 'consumer' type functional interface?Got to know from other answers that method references can be substituted for any kind of lambda expression. Thank you for answering my question.